# Ajax post to PHP and Directly goes to next page

Tags: php, ajax

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "proses.php",
     data: {
         noKartu: noK,
         nmKartu: nP,
         tujuan: bT,
         idBus: iB,
         jum: ind,
         noKursi: nKursi,
         biaya: harga,
         tgl: tK
     }
 }); 
</script>
```

What I want to do is after ajax post the data to proses.php, the page directly goes to next page.
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by next page ?

Comment: I mean load another page

Answer (score 3):

You can do actions once the AJAX has successfully posted (such as, moving onto the next page) using the success callback, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "proses.php",
  data: {
    noKartu: noK,
    nmKartu: nP,
    tujuan: bT,
    idBus: iB,
    jum: ind,
    noKursi: nKursi,
    biaya: harga,
    tgl: tK
  },
  success: function(){
    window.location="nextpage.php";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a success callback on your ajax and redirect to to the next page like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "proses.php",
    data: {
        /*insert your data here*/
    },
    success: function (data) {
        location.href = "http://your.next.page";
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "proses.php",
        data: {
            noKartu: noK,
            nmKartu: nP,
            tujuan: bT,
            idBus: iB,
            jum: ind,
            noKursi: nKursi,
            biaya: harga,
            tgl: tK
        }
    });
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
</script>
```

This would be forward you to www.google.com without care about result. Since the nature of AJAX is async we should take advance of that. But this practice is not recommended by me ... better has a callback implemented. But oh well since you don't care about the result.

Comment: if it's worked for you I'm happy. But IMO it's a bad practice ... you should implement callback function then reload later. Have a nice day